# Web application - restrict access to uploaded files

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload, acl

I have a problem. I am developing a web application and will be uploaded files for the staff (ie: resume, criminal record check, etc). These files get a name that includes the time, name of staff and type of file similar to: John_Doe_Resume_12-12-12-16:36:23.PDF. So all the files will be in a directory, so this file could be accessed directly by inputting the file path into the browser.

I still need to be able to access these files from within the PHP web application to download when I need them. One possible solution I thought of was to store the file information in mysql but this would be a lot of work and extra server load.

Is there a way to restrict access to a directory so only the PHP web application can access them? (ie: so people cannot directly input the file url to download)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put

```
deny from all
```

in your .htaccess file. Put this file in the directory you which to be unreachable by direct url. Your php scripts will be able to get in the directory since .htaccess is influencing apache

In php you do

```
$filename = "yourfilename.pdf";
$filepath = "./../rel_path_to_restricted_folder/";


if(file_exists($filepath . $filename))
{
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; '. $filename);
    header('Content-type: ' . mime_content_type($filepath . $filename));
    readfile($filepath . $filename);
}
else
{

    echo("File not found"); 
}
```

Voilà ;)